# Css variables declared in :root block in styles.scss are invalid

Tags: css, angular, sass, css-variables

In my angular 11 app I am trying to globally use css variables to declare global colors.

In my **styles.scss** I have:

```
:root{
    --primary : #0b68e8;
    --secondary:#ABCFFF;
}
.test-class{
    background: var(--primary);
}
```

When I am applying that class in one of mine components I can see that var was not properly taken from declared variables:

[image]

I tried to find any solution , but cant resolve it. Do you maybe know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.test-class{
    background: #{var(--primary)};
}
```

BTW, if you're using sccs, why not use sass variables?

```
$primary: #0b68e8;
.test-class{
    background: $primary;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Eliseo I just wanted to follow approach for handling multiple themes in angular apps like here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-themes-for-your-angular-7-apps-using-css-variables-69251690e9c5/

Comment: and btw that didnt help

Comment: Looks like work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-c7irbx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html