# Switching between themes (scss) in angular project

Tags: angular, sass, themes

My angular project uses bootstrap as its main styling framework. I also created two separate .scss files to change the bootstrap variables for the light and dark themes. Since angular uses the same bootstrap source for both themes, is there a way to switch between them on the fly once the app has been initialized?

Comment: in this SO (in the comments) use css variables to change to a dark mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806883/css-variables-declared-in-root-block-in-styles-scss-are-invalid/67868617#67868617